# How can I mock complex (url) API with Retrofit

Tags: android, api, retrofit, okhttp, moshi

I need to do something as this website describes: https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2016/11/22/mocking-api-calls.html[1](https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2016/11/22/mocking-api-calls.html)

I need to mock my API on certain flavour using some json file, implementing my own OkHttp Interceptor. I'm able todo this with simple url, but how can I do this if the url is more complex, for example:

> /hello/world/{myName}/{mySurname}

?

In my custom interceptor the url is already "compiled", but I need to read my json files based on theirs filename, so I need {myName} and {mySurname} as strings. I think I should read the url's annotations, but I can't find any example of this.

My source code is similar to the above website, i have my API.kt:

```
internal interface API {
    @GET("hello/world/{myName}/{mySurname}")
    fun hello(
        @Path(value = "myName") name: String,
        @Path(value = "mySurname") surname: String
    ): Observable...
}
```

and my ServiceFactory.kt where I implement my custom Interceptor:

```
val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
httpClient.interceptors().add(Interceptor { chain ->
    // here I have my request and response
    // here the request URL is already compiled, for example: /hello/world/steve/jobs
})
```

So I think I should read the url's annotations implementing my own **ConverterFactory**:

```
retrofit
    .client(httpClient.build())
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build()
    .create<API>(API::class.java)
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks guys!

Comment: can you share some of your codes?

Answer (score 0):

If  you can give more context about what you're trying to do exactly, that'd be helpful. From what I understand, you would not need a custom interceptor just for testing. You can use `MockWebServer`, enqueue requests in order and tests the responses in order. `MockWebServer` has a `takeRequest()` method using which you can assert the headers, URL, request params etc.

Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

Comment: I don't want to start a new local server. I need only to use mock json file as response for specific flavour